# How can I restrict the input of decimals points to only 1 in C#?

Tags: c#

The code below restricts everything I need restricted, but it allows the user to input more than 1 decimal point

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtOperand2.Text, 
    "[^0-9],[.],[\b]"))  
{
       MessageBox.Show("Please enter only numbers."); 
       txtOperand2.Text = txtOperand2.Text.Remove(txtOperand2.Text.Length - 1);
}
```

Comment: If you're trying to validate a decimal use `Decimal.TryParse`, not a Regular expression. `TryParse` is more useful and handles things like localization.

Comment: It would help if you could show few examples of what is considered valid and what is considered not valid.

Answer (score 2):

As per [@DourHighArch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22437/dour-high-arch)'s worthy comment. If you are just checking for a valid decimal to a certain number of places, and you want a fast culture aware solution (and other configurability like [number styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netcore-3.1)).

Instead of regex, you could do something like this. [`decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) and checking how many decimal places it has via some means.

> Converts the string representation of a number to its Decimal
> equivalent. A return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded
> or failed.

**Given**

```
// gets the decimal places by deconstruction
public static int GetDecimalPlaces(decimal d)
   => BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(d)[3])[2];
```

**Usage**

```
if (decimal.TryParse(argument, out var d) && GetDecimalPlaces(d) == 1)
    Console.WriteLine("You win, play again?");
```

<sub>*Add pepper and salt to taste*</sub>